# Rearrange an array in maximum minimum form by javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, output

In output array should be[1st highest, 1st lowest, 2nd highest, 2nd lowest and so on] Eg:-
Input  : arr[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7} 
Output : arr[] = {7, 1, 6, 2, 5, 3, 4}

Comment: Please provide more input to your question

Comment: Is the input array already sorted?

Comment: Given information is not up to mark.please share some detail So that we can help

Comment: @gurvinder372 no input array is not sorted

Comment: @Dream_Cap  output array should have an element in order which shows the highest element and the lowest element and then 2nd highest and 2nd lowest and then 3rd highest and 3rd lowest..like this. u can make your own array.

Comment: @AshishBhavsar output array should have an element in order which shows the highest element and the lowest element and then 2nd highest and 2nd lowest and then 3rd highest and 3rd lowest..like this. u can make your own array.

Comment: Please don't ask without showing at least an approach of your own (not necessarily code, but something that shows us that you at least put _some_ thought into this yourself already.) One simple approach could be to sort the array so that you got the values in descending order, and then alternately take one value from the front and one from the back, and put them into a new array ... sth like that.

Answer (score 2):

First, use valid JS syntax.

Iterate the array, incrementing by two. On each iteration, pop the last item off the array and splice it into the position at the current index.

```js
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];

arr.sort((a, b) => a-b);

for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i+=2) {
  arr.splice(i, 0, arr.pop());
}

console.log(arr);
```

Comment: this does not provide the expected output

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest: Well, I momentarily had the position requirements reversed in my mind. Just needed to remove the `+ 1` in the `.splice()`. Fixed it as you were commenting.

Comment: thanks it works but instead of arr.sort((a, b) => a-b);...arr.sort((a, b) => b-a); will give the desired output, but it worked :)

Comment: @ManiSingh: Yep, works that way too. I updated the answer to fix it at the `.splice()` instead of at the `.sort()`. Either way is good. :)

Answer (score 2):

You could address the wanted index where to put the value. This proposal requires a sorted array.

It works without mutating the array.

```js
var array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
    result = array.reduce(function (r, a, i, aa) {
        r[i < aa.length >> 1 ? i * 2 + 1 : (aa.length - i - 1) * 2] = a;
        return r;
    }, []);
    
console.log(result);
```

Easy solution. With mutation.

```js
var array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
    result = [],
    action = 'shift',
    toggle = { pop: 'shift', shift: 'pop' };

while (array.length) result.push(array[action = toggle[action]]());

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Minor detail but you would need to sort the array first.

Answer (score 1):

Quick and dirty, seems to work

```js
function maxminform(arr){
  arr = arr.sort();
  var res = [];
  for(var i=0, j = arr.length-1; i <= j; i++, j--){
    if(i != j) res.push(arr[j]);
    res.push(arr[i]);
  }
  return res;
}


var a = [5,6,2,3,8,1,4,7];
console.log(maxminform(a));
```

Answer (score 1):

Here I first created a sorted array, doing `[].concat` is also a nice way to prevent altering the original array.

I then map the results,.  If the modulus of the mapped index = 0, we take the next number from the end of the array, or else we take from the start.  the `dv` variable will be how far from the begging and end we take the value.

```js
const arr = [1, 7, 4, 5, 3, 6, 2];

const sorted = 
  [].concat(arr).sort((a,b) => a-b).map((a, ix, arr) => {
    const isEnd = ix % 2;
    const dv = Math.trunc(ix / 2);
    if (!isEnd) return arr[arr.length -1 -dv];
    else return arr[dv];
  });

console.log(sorted);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var a = [1, 2, 3, 7, 5, 6, 4];
var ans = [];

a.sort(function(a, b) {
  return a - b;
})

//For Even length
if (a.length % 2 == 0) {
  for (i = 0; i < a.length / 2; i++) {
    ans.push(a[a.length - 1 - i]);
    ans.push(a[i]);
  }
}
//For Odd length
else {
  ans.push(a[a.length - 1])
  a.pop();
  for (i = 0; i < a.length / 2; i++) {
    ans.push(a[i]);

    ans.push(a[a.length - 1 - i]);
  }
}
console.log(ans);
```

Answer (score 0):

To get consecutive ***max/min*** pairs ...

```js
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], 
    result = [];
 
for(var i=0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    var max = Math.max.apply(null, arr), min = Math.min.apply(null, arr);
    arr.splice(arr.indexOf(max), 1);
    arr.splice(arr.indexOf(min), 1);
    result.push(max, min);
}
if (arr.length) result.push(arr.pop());

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function maxMin(arr){ 
let temp = [];
let small = 0;
let large = arr.length - 1;

for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  if (small < large) {
  temp.push(arr[large]);
  temp.push(arr[small]);
  small++;
  large--; 
   }

}
//length of array if its  not even
if(arr.length % 2 !==0){
  let i = Math.floor(arr.length/2)
  temp.push(arr[i])
}
 return temp;
}
```